# Semantic ui ready.function() value change by calling onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, user-interface, semantic-ui

```
var val;

function imagepop(nval) {
    val = nval;
}

$(document)
    .ready(function() {
        $('.ui.selection.dropdown').dropdown();
        $('.ui.menu .ui.dropdown').dropdown({
            on: 'hover'
        });
        $('.ui.button')
            .popup({
                popup: $('.' + val + '.fluid.popup'),
                on: 'click'
            });
    });
```

I am using this code to button for change `val` by using this button

`<div class="ui primary button" onclick="imagepop(<?php echo$row['idproperty']; ?>)">`

I need to change the value when i click on it

Comment: What should `val` be initially set to ? What is purpose of `imagepop` ?

Comment: Val is not initiate, imagepop is function its sending defferent ID and its poping up some js in the code

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle for us?